# mailchimp Create Merge Fields in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, mailchimp

When I click on button Create Merge Fields I got an error in a log file

2019-10-29T16:47:37+00:00 DEBUG (7): Merge Max Limit Exceeded for Api Call: [https://us15.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/7e3c61605f/merge-fields/] using method [POST]
    Detail: [You have exceeded the maximum number of 30 merge fields for this list.]
    Params:
        {"name":"Middle Name/Initial","type":"text","tag":"MNAME","public":true}

i use last mailchimp extension version. 
My Customer Fields Mapping:
[image]

What is wrong in my config?

Comment: check your mailchimp account how many fields there.

Comment: @SohelRana which section in MailChimp? Thanx